# Time interval between two method calls

Tags: objective-c, ios, client, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

In CoreBluetooth, the didDiscoverPeripheral method is called when the scan reveals that a Bluetooth device is nearby. I'd like to measure the time between two calls and store it in a variable. Can I use a kind of time stamp for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Create a 'NSDate' object before calling the method like `NSDate startTime = [NSDate date];` and get the time interval after the method call to which you want to get the time interval. `NSTimeInterval interval = [startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];`

Comment: Thanks afnan for your answer. However, how will I solve the retain problem with NSDate? The interval will be calculated in another method so that I need to create a property and retain the NSDate object. If I'd like to update the object (startTime = nil & startTime = [NSDate date] retain]) when the didDiscoverMethod is called, the interval calculation still takes the old NSDate object. Is there a more straightforward way of storing an updated time stamp in a variable?